# Prime number question

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can somebody please give me a hint on how to start this question:

Let $a$ and $n$ be two positive integers with $a,n ≥ 2$. Assume that $a^n−1$ is a prime number. Prove that $a = 2$ and $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: Looks similar to the Fermat's Little theorem.

Comment: $a^n - 1$ can always be factorized to $(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+1)$, ergo $a=2$.

Comment: Also $a^{pq}-1$ can be transformed to $(a^p-1)(a^{p(q-1)}+a^{p(q-2)}+...+1)$, ergo n is a prime. Bingo!

Comment: The Little Theorem doesn't apply here... FLT doesn't say anything about $a^n-1$, it is concerned with $a^{p-1}$ where p is prime. In fact if $a^n-1$ is prime, n+1 _can't_ be prime because according to the theorem $p|(a^{p-1}-1)$

Answer (score 7):

$$
a^n - 1 = (a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a^2+a^1+a^0).
$$
That's a factorization, showing that $a^n$ is not prime unless the first factor $a-1$ is $1$, so that $a=2$.

If $n$ is not prime, then
$$
a^n = a^{pq} = (a^p)^q,
$$
and $a^p$ is not $2$, so the same thing that happens when $a\ne 2$ happens when $a^p\ne 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you need a well known source (that proves this theorem), the book `Introduction to the theory of numbers' by Hardy and Wright is a good place to start. If not from a book, I proceed to give the argument (seeking first to show that $a=2$). Note if $a^n-1=p$, where $p$ is prime, then $p=(a-1)(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^k)$ as already mentioned. If a prime can be written as $p=AB$, where $A$ and $B$ are positive, then $A=1$ or $B=1$. In this case (why?) we would be forced to assume $a-1=1$. Thus $a=2$.

Note parts of this proof have already been mentioned by other people in this comments. So I thank them. Now [we are trying to show, if $a^n-1=p$ then $n=q$ where $q$ is prime] assume $2^n-1=p$. We can do this as we have already shown $a=2$. If (we assume, seeking a contradiction) $n$ is $\textit{not}$ prime, then let $n=cd$, where $c>1$ and $d>1$. Then $2^c-1$ divides $2^{cd}-1$. As $c \neq 1$, $2^c-1>1$, and $2^c-1$ is a factor of $p$ (or $2^{cd}-1$), so we have a prime $p$ with a factor that is higher than $1$. Unless $2^c-1=p$, which means $2^{c}-1=2^{cd}-1$ (and hence $d=1$), we have the required contradiction. Cheers.